# In class C<V extends A> and (with anyMethod returning A in class A), how do I assign an object returned by anyMethod to reference variable of type V?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, abstract

```
abstract class A
{
    abstract public A anyMethod();
}
class B extends A
{
    @Override
    public B anyMethod()
    {
         return (new B());
    }
}
class C<V extends A>
{
     V temp1,new_temp;
     public void c_method()
     {
     temp1 = new_temp.anyMethod();
    }
}
public class test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

    }
}
```

When I write

```
temp1 = (V) new_temp.anyMethod
```

the compiler shows :
Note: /home/workstation/Desktop/new/test.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Now, I know that a class file has been created, but how do I remove the "unchecked or unsafe operations". Is there a "safe" way to implement the above?

Comment: This compiles just fine. An instance of `B` is, by definition, also an instance of `A`. What compiler/IDE are you using?

Comment: Sorry! Corrected the question.

Comment: If you want that to work you'll have to change the return type of the method in B to B.

Answer (score 4):

`B b2 = (B) b1.anyMethod()` you have to cast it to `B`.

Or

Change the return type of `public A anyMethod()` to `B`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler sees that the declared return type of the method is A. It doesn't matter that what you actually return is a B. The easiest way to fix it is to change the return type of the method in B to B.

Comment: This is most likely the safest way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler may not be recognizing that B is of type A.
Perhaps try this in the overridden method:

```
A a = this;
return a;
```

This way the compiler would know that you returned an object with an A type variable.

EDIT: My answer above is wrong. After your update, the problem is clear that anyMethod returns an object with a reference type A, but you are setting it to a reference type B. Thus, you need to type cast it, so:

```
B b2 = (B)b1.anyMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to change the return type of the overriding method.  When you override a method, you are not allowed to change the types of the parameters.  However, you *are* allowed to change the result type, if the new result type is a subclass of the result type of the method you're overriding.  Thus, this is legal:

```
abstract class A
{
    abstract public A anyMethod();
}
class B extends A
{
    @Override
    public A anyMethod()
    {
         return this;
    }
}
```

The result type doesn't have to be related to the class you're extending, either.  This is also legal:

```
abstract class A
{
    abstract public CharSequence anyOtherMethod();
}
class B extends A
{
    @Override
    public String anyOtherMethod()
    {
         return "that";
    }
}
```

because `String` implements `CharSequence`.  The important thing is that any code that has an `A` and calls this method on it expecting to get a `CharSequence` result will still get it, because every `String` is a `CharSequence`.  The consequence is that when the compiler knows it's working with a `B` object, it can assume the result of the method will be in the narrower class:

```
  B b1 = new B();
  B b2 = b1.anyMethod();  
  String s1 = b1.anyOtherMethod();
```

On the other hand:

```
  A b3 = new B();
  B b4 = b3.anyMethod();  // illegal
  String s2 = b3.anyOtherMethod();  // illegal
```

aren't allowed, because the compiler has to treat `b3` as if it could belong to *any* subclass of `A`.

(This is called *covariance*, and I don't believe it was supported in the earlier versions of Java, but I'm not sure what version introduced it.)